# Calculating next letter in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically a table has a header-column and a sequence-column. The sequence consists of 'aa', 'ab', 'ac' etc.

I'm trying to create a function that given a header input, it gives the next possible sequence. For example if the last sequence that starts with an 'a' ends with 'd' (sequence 'ad'), it gives 'ae'.
First I select the current 'highest' sequence (MAX), and then I update the second letter

My code:

```
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fctCalculateNextSeqCode]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @Input nvarchar(50)
)
RETURNS nvarchar
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @NewSeq nvarchar(50)
    DECLARE @OldSeq nvarchar(50)

    SET @OldSeq = (select Max(SMTRPD_Sequence) from dbo.TbOrgSM_Transactions_PriceLines_Definition where SMTRPD_Header2 = @Input)

    --first character remains, second character is next in alphabet
    select @NewSeq = LEFT(@OldSeq,1) + CHAR(ASCII(RIGHT(@OldSeq,1))+1);

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @NewSeq

END
```

When I try to run the function it only returns the first character of the sequence, not the second. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to consider an alternative design - just *store* an `int` value and then, as a *formatting* step (and not necessarily even done in the database, but it could be), convert that number into base-26 where you're using the characters `a-z` as the digits.

Comment: Pay attention to the type mismatch: DECLARE @NewSeq nvarchar(50)
 and ...  + CHAR(ASCII(RIGHT(@OldSeq,1))+1); You should use NCHAR() and UNICODE() instead CHAR() and ASCII()

Comment: And why you declare your vars as nvarchar(50)? In your algorithm will always be processed only 2 characters. You can declare as nchar(2)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'm going to change to code. My sql skills aren't that pretty at this very moment...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should write `RETURNS` as `RETURNS nvarchar(50)` as default length of `nvarchar` is 1 char long.

**Edit**

For `nchar [ ( n ) ]` and `nvarchar [ ( n | max ) ]` when n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified with the `CAST` function, the default length is 30.

Please find more information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186939(v=sql.100).aspx)

Comment: Actually, sometimes the default length is `30`. Read this [article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) by Aaron Bertrand for more details.

Comment: @wewesthemenace when n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified with the CAST function, the default length is 30.

Comment: @Deepshikha, is that always true? Do you have a reference to support that?

Comment: Please find the reference here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186939(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @Deepshikha, hah! Why didn't I see that? Anyway, thanks for the link.